# Would it make any sense to order ASIC miners now?

Tags: mining-profitability, butterfly-labs

I'd like to order some Jalapeños (the 5 Gh/s models) from Butterfly Labs; I'm thinking about 4 of them.

I know I'd be looking to a delivery time of 3-6 months; and I know perfectly well that mining difficulty will increase dramatically in the next few months.

With current BitCoin exchange rates, it would take ~10 BTC to repay the cost of the Jalapeños; but will they be able to mine 10 BTC in a reasonable time, 3-6 months from now?

Would it make any sense at all to place the order now?